# Tracking undefined wildcard subdomains via a single google analytic property

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

What is the simplest method to track wildcard subdomains from one single tracking property using google analytics.

The subdomains cannot be pre defined in the google analytics dashboard, they are wildcard subdomains setup by customers, so I need this to work using one piece js code.

Is it possible for me add the subdomain via the javascript code, like a meta field/var that can be filtered in the google analytics dashboard?

For example something like this..

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-123456789-0"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', 'UA-123456789-0');
  gtag('subdomain', '<?php echo $subdomain; ?>'); // like this for example
</script>
```

Any suggestions or pointers would be awesome thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't do anything, you can already filter by the Hostname dimension.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, sorry I had to wait for analytics to start working. I couldn't find dimensions in the analytics dashboard but I searched hostname and it's give me sessions and percentages for each one. Kind of solves my issue thanks.